# C++ code optimization on memory access and type convertion in Android

Tags: android, c++, optimization, interpolation, video-processing

I am doing video processing using JNI in Android.

The below is one snippet of one frame processing (This is an interpolation of intensity for a pixel at (x,y):

dynamic_px1_matrix is a short int pointer to a list of x1 values.

```
short int *buffer_py1_matrix = (short int *) av_malloc(rowNum * colNum * sizeof(short int));
short int *dynamic_py1_matrix = buffer_py1_matrix;
```

Similarly for dynamic_py1_matrix.

dynamic_pa1_matrix is a short int pointer to a list of round(a1*100) values.

Actually I need a decimal (0-1) value for a1. In order to save the memory space, I save it as a short int by doing round(a1*100)

```
short int x1 = *(dynamic_px1_matrix);
dynamic_px1_matrix ++;
short int x2 = x1 + 1;
short int y1 = *(dynamic_py1_matrix);
dynamic_py1_matrix ++;
short int y2 = y1 + 1;

double a1 = 0.01 * (*(dynamic_pa1_matrix));
dynamic_pa1_matrix ++;
double a2 = 1 - a1;
double b1 = 0.01 * (*(dynamic_pb1_matrix));
dynamic_pb1_matrix ++;
double b2 = 1 - b1;

pFrameYUV420PFlat -> data[0][j + i * linesize_pFrameYUV420PFlat] = (a2
        * inVStruct.inFrame -> data[0][x1 + y1 * linesize_inFrame]
        + a1 * inVStruct.inFrame -> data[0][x2 + y1 * linesize_inFrame]) * b2
        + (a2 * inVStruct.inFrame -> data[0][x1 + y2 * linesize_inFrame]
                + a1 * inVStruct.inFrame -> data[0][x2 + y2 * linesize_inFrame]) * b1;
```

However, it takes a lot of time (0.45 sec/frame), only slightly shorter than directly calculation of the values of x1, x2, y1, y2, a1, a2, b1, b2.

For comparison purpose, if I instead directly set random values for those variables for x1, x2, y1, y2, a1, a2, b1, b2, the processing speed is 0.15 sec/frame.

I am not familiar with optimization.
Would you give me a hint where to improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the Java and JNI code as well? I don't think your issue is in the C code. There may be mallocs going on as a result of going from Java to C through JNI.

Comment: @JustinDanielson: Sorry I cannot share the code. malloc is done in JNI. For comparison purpose, if I instead directly set random values for those variables for x1, x2, y1, y2, a1, a2, b1, b2, the processing speed is 0.15 sec/frame.

Comment: What is the prototype for the function? I'm trying to understand what you're sending from Java to the C layer. If you're pushing down large data structures. Every piece of data in Java is copied outside of the JVM when using JNI/C. You may only need to change your memory management on the Java side to fix things. Using the ByteBuffer, you can allocate a contiguous segment of memory off the JVM.

If you can't show us more code, can you profile the running of the application? Use Traceview.

Comment: @JustinDanielson: All is performed in JNI. Nothing related to Java. So actually I could omit Android in this question if it leads confusion. Maybe I could reprogram it in C++ and see whether access of memory Does take such amount of time. I haven't used profile in Android before. I will try it later. Thanks.

Comment: You should look into RenderScript as well.

Comment: Thanks. After some research on the Internet, I think Android CPU is slow on this. I may need GPU to improve it. But thank you very much!

Comment: RenderScript was designed specifically for this. Good luck